# SSl not working on checkout page in magento?

Tags: magento, ssl, magento-1.7, ssl-certificate

I am working on magento 1.7 version.I enabled the option for SSl from back-end.Now checkout page not working.It is showing "The page isn't redirecting properly".

I did following settings for this:-

system->configuration->Web     (**Auto-redirect to Base URL**) set to **No**

system->configuration->Web     (**Use Web Server Rewrites**) set to **No**

system->configuration->Web     (**Use Secure URLs in Front-end**) set to **Yes**

system->configuration->Web     (**Use SID on Front-end**) set to **Yes**

and ssl certificate is already install on server.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Made sure the secure base url is https://www.yourstore.com/?

Make sure your web server rewrites are on.
Make sure the auto-redirect to base url is on, you'll suffer SEO penalties if google considers your site duplicate content as it is responding on both www.yoursite.com and
yoursite.com

Your other settings are fine, effectively everything in your post should be set to yes!

Comment: This is not working.I set yes all options as you said above but still showing "The page isn't redirecting properly".I am using onestep checkout